# play java framework 2.6.7 NettyServerProvider

Tags: java, playframework-2.6

We are in the process to migrate from 2.5.3 to 2.6.7.
Since play now supports AKKA stream as default, we specified netty server using property in application conf.

```
    # Required for Play Framework 2.6.x
    play.server {
      # The server provider class name
      provider = "play.core.server.NettyServerProvider"
    }
```

But at the time of startup, below error is reported -->

```
Couldn't find ServerProvider class 'play.core.server.NettyServerProvider'
```

Couldn't find much in the documentation. 
Would really appreciate any pointer.

Answer (score -1):

After looking into play code figured out that netty server library needs to be added as a dependency.